# Lookbehind alternative with both lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, clojurescript, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm looking for a regex to split user supplied strings on the `:` character but not when the user has escaped the colon `\:` or it's part of a url, e.g. `https://stackoverflow..`.
In javascript the majority of browsers don't yet support lookbehinds. Is it possible to apply some other approach for the lookbehind part?

In clojure/ Clojurescript on Chrome (which does support lookbehinds) this regex does the trick:

```
#"(?<!\):(?!//)"
```

but not in Safari (for example).

Comment: You could use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) in combination with [slevithan/xregexp-lookbehind2.js](https://gist.github.com/slevithan/2387872).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that currently browsers aren't supporting the lookbehind, which is required to find and negate the prefix `\` so we don't include `\:`.

One workaround (not very pretty but it works) is to first substitute the `\:` with some "symbol" you know will not occur naturally in your text, do your split, and the substitute back any `\:`.

For example, this method will return an empty element "" if you have "::" in your string:

```js
let regex = /:(?!\/\/)/

//original string literal \: has to be expressed as \\:
let str = "http://example.com::hello:dolly:12\\:00\\:PM";

//substitute out any \: 
str = str.replace(/\\:/g,"<colon>"); //http://example.com::hello:dolly:12<colon>00<colon>PM

//now we split 'normally' without lookbehind
let arr = str.split(regex); //[ 'http://example.com', '', 'hello', 'dolly', '12\\:00\\:PM' ]

//substitute back \:
arr = arr.map(element => element.replace(/<colon>/g, "\\:")); //[ 'http://example.com', '', 'hello', 'dolly', '12\\:00\\:PM' ]

console.log(arr);
```

If you're just after non-empty elements you can just do an `arr.filter(Boolean)` on it, or just use @Skeeve's matching solution as it's more elegant for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to not search for the separator but to search for the elements:

```
var str="this:is\\:a:test:https://stackoverflow:80:test::test";
var elements= str.match(/((?:[^\\:]|\\:|:\/\/)+)/g);
// elements= [ "this", "is\\:a", "test", "https://stackoverflow", "80", "test", "test" ]
```

1. The elements may not be empty (Observe the"+" in the regexp) and how the empty element between the last 2 "test" is missing
2. You forgot that an URL can contain multiple colons. What about `http://me:password@myhost.com:8080/path?value=d:f'

Besides these I think it should work for you.

I think you can only overcome the disadvantages with a more or less sophisticated loop using regexp-exec.

P.S. I know the grouping isn't required here, but if you want to use it in regexp-exec, you'll need it.
Disadvantages:

P.P.S. Fixed the typo @chatnoir found

Comment: Shouldn't "ist\:a" be returned as an element instead of being split into "ist" and "a"?

Comment: I think your str should read="this:ist\\:a..." (i.e.  `\\:` to denote `\:`)

Answer (score 0):

You might also make use of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and pass a function as the second parameter.

You could use a pattern to match what you don't want and capture in a group what you want to keep. Then you can replace the part that you want to keep with a marker just as in the approach of @chatnoir and afterwards split on that marker.

```
:\/\/\S+|\\:|(:)
```

**Explanation**

- `:\/\/\S+` Match `://` followed by 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `|` Or
- `\\:` Match `\:`
- `|` Or
- `(:)` Capture a `:` in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HgFwcX/1)

```js
let pattern = /:\/\/\S+|\\:|(:)/g;
let str = "string\\: or https://www.example.com:8000 or split:me or te\\:st or \\:test or notsplit\\:me:splitted or \\: or ftp://example.com :";

str = str.replace(pattern, function(match, group1) {
  return group1 === undefined ? match : "<split>"
});

console.log(str.split("<split>").filter(Boolean));
```